# How to navigate from one ViewController to another using a button. Swift 3 (No StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I would like to navigate from my initial ViewController named "HomeController" to another view Controller named "CalendarController". I would like to do this by using a button called "CalendarButton". I would also like to do this with no reference to storyboard. Thanks

error says: Pushing a navigation controller is not supported

```
import UIKit
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(31, green: 194, blue: 31)
    collectionView!.isScrollEnabled = false
    collectionView? .register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for:indexPath) as! MenuCell
       cell.calendarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(calendar), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
    }

    func calendar() {
       let objVC: CalendarController! = CalendarController()
       let aObjNavi = UINavigationController(rootViewController: objVC!)
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aObjNavi, animated: true)

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) ->Int {
    return 1

   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)

   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
   }

}
```

// separate swift file

```
  class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell{
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
  }
  func setupViews() {

  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

}
  class MenuCell: BaseCell{   

  lazy var calendarButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Calender", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    return button
}()

  func calendar() {
    let newViewController = CalendarController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: The app delegate is not a view controller

Comment: Show the code like: class HomeController...

Comment: hope this edit helps

Comment: @ErikLopez is your HomeController in a navigation stack ??

Answer (score 1):

Cell doesn't have navigation controller. Only view controller have navigation controller.

If you want to access

```
 func calendar() {
    let newViewController = CalendarController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
 }
```

then change some code like this in HomeController

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for:indexPath) as! MenuCell
    cell.calendarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(calendar), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

 func calendar() {
    let newViewController = CalendarController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

and Make Sure your HomeController is embeded in **NavigationController**

Or You can use delegate to access **func Calender(){...}**

Comment: I made changes to the HomeController and know I'm getting a error sayingPushing a navigation controller is not supported. What do i need to do next?

Comment: when you are instantiate your HomeController then it must be embed in **NavigationViewController**.

Answer (score 0):

As i have seen your code you haven't embedded **Navigation controller**. 
Push works in a stack. So you need to embedded navigation controller programmatically in your code.

This link can help you better :
[Embedding navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42810501/8432814)

Comment: i updated my code and now im getting a "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported" error. Please help I'm a newbie