# Set a default back button on a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift4, back-button, uinavigationitem

*short*: I don´t understand how to programmatically add the **default** back button.

*long*: I have been asked to write an iOS app, without any previous experience I decided 
to follow the advices and code given by [Nicola Zaghini](https://academy.realm.io/posts/break-the-monoloth-with-b-viper-modules/).

In the [code](https://github.com/nzaghini/b-viper) given along with the article, I really don´t understand 
where does the back button come from.

The app has three screens

- one to choose a city (folder WeatherLocation)
- one that displays all
  cities that have been already choosen (folder WeatherList)
- one that
  displays the weather for a city clicked in the list (folder
  WeatherDetail)

There is `+` button for `WeatherLocation`:

[image]

This button is added in the code but I can not find where
and how is coded the back button in `WeatherDetails` (see above), and how is coded the action to do when one click the back button.

[image]

I search the web and found how to set a button in the NavigationBar:

```
let leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Item", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
    barButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.red
    return barButtonItem
}()


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
}
```

I also found that there is a [backBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624958-backbarbuttonitem)
but I could not find how to properly use this property.

Moreover in the code of Nicola Zaghini there is nothing like `backBarButtonItem` to enable the 
back button, neither in the xib and storyboard.

Can someone give me some hints about on how to set the back button ?

Comment: Your view controllers should be embedded in a `UINavigationController`. When you push a viewController in the back button appears by default unless you set `leftBarButton`

Comment: Visit following URL <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809834/how-to-add-a-navigation-controller-programmatically-in-code-but-not-as-initial-v>?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!!

In the [code](https://github.com/nzaghini/b-viper) of Nicola Zaghini the secret to have a default back button resides (for example) in the function `navigateToWeatherDetail` in the class `WeatherListDefaultRouter` where the new ViewController is pushed on a  `NavigationController`:

```
func navigateToWeatherDetail(withLocation location: Location) {
    if let weatherDetailVC = self.weatherDetailBuilder()?.buildWeatherDetailModule(withLocation: location) {
        self.viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(weatherDetailVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```